# source /dev/stdin doesn't work as expected

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

Let's start with simple tests that work for me to check that `source /dev/stdin` can be used at all.

```
# echo -ne 'echo a\necho b\n' | source /dev/stdin
a
b
```

Now I would like to source an actual function.

```
# echo -ne 'f() { echo a; }\n' | source /dev/stdin
# f
-bash: f: command not found
```

Now let's try with a temporary file.

```
# echo -ne 'f() { echo a; }\n' > tempf
# source tempf
# f
a
```

So the temporary file works. But it's very incovenient in my case and I don't see any valid reason why the pipe shouldn't work just as well.

```
# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

For completeness, the actual use case is to carfully select which parts of a file will be included, in order to work around over a limitation in Gentoo portage.

```
post_src_unpack() {
    if type epatch_user > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        epatch_user || die
    else
        awk \
            '/^# @FUNCTION: / { p = 0 } /^# @FUNCTION: epatch(_user)?$/ { p = 1; } p { print  }' \
            /usr/portage/eclass/eutils.eclass | source /dev/stdin || die
        epatch_user || die
        unset epatch
        unset epatch_user
    fi
}
```

The purpose of the code is to extract just two required functions `epatch` and `epatch_user` from a source file with lots of functions, make them available in the current shell, run one of them (which in turn uses the other), and remove them. The final goal is to workaround the limitation of Gentoo that only ebuilds inheriting `eutils` have access to `epatch_user`.

Comment: I guess you could put your awk command inside a `$()` process substitution, and then `eval` that... if you can guarantee that the string you're passing to `eval` is safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

```
source /dev/stdin < <(echo -ne 'f() { echo a; }\n')
```

or

```
source <(echo -ne 'f() { echo a; }\n')
```

This works in bash 4.1.5, for some reason it doesn't work in 3.2.48.

Comment: I like the second one better, the `/dev/stdin` is clearly redundant. The process substitution is bash-specific, right? It's local Gentoo scripting so I think it's safe to require bash. The requirement for a recent version is trivial in that case.

Comment: It's hard to choose the best answer as some answers contain an explanation which was very helpful to me, some offer a portable way which may be useful for others, but this one definitely contains what I would like to use to avoid running `source` in a subshell.

Comment: Process substitution isn't POSIX, but it's in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`.

Answer (score 5):

Each part of [pipelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02) run in [separated processes, or own subshell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12). So when your pipelines finished, your current shell does not know anything about function `f`.

With `bash` (`ksh`, `pdksh`, `zsh`, `mksh` or shell that support [Here-String](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings)), your can use:

```
$ source /dev/stdin <<<'f() { echo a; }'
$ f
a
```

POSIXly, you should use [Here-Document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) and [dot](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot):

```
$ . /dev/stdin <<'EOF'
> f() { echo a; }
> EOF

$ f
a
```

Comment: The explanation works for me, indeed I wasn't aware of the subshells. The solution works for the example but not for the original task that is at the end of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The commands in a pipe are separate processes, hence the function definition that is sourced from `/dev/stdin` is lost as soon as the pipe completes. That is why the pipe show different results to the usage of the temporary file.

In your use case the `eval` as suggested by PM 2Ring would be the way to go.